# apex:outputField not aligning text to the right

Tags: apex, visualforce, email, template, outputfield

I have a visualforce email template, and I have a field with rich text where the text is Right aligned.

I need to print it in the email attachment as pdf but it's always shown as left aligned, i tried with multiple tags and CSS but nothing seems to be working with the apex:outputField. The only thing that worked was to create a table with float:right property but just moves the text, to the right, it's not really aligning it to the right margin.
Do you have any idea how to solve this?

```
  <apex:outputField value="{!relatedTo.Rich_Text__c}"/>
```

Comment: Visualforce PDF rendering is very limited and doesnot support all the latest CSS. Check this [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_output_pdf_considerations.htm) it is mentioned that it does not support formatting markup contained within the contents of rich text area fields added to the page.

Comment: So there is no solution i guess?

Comment: I Had such issue in the past...In my case it worked after I set the body style to: text-align: right; , however this only moved the items to the right. In case the field itself contains words with right-toleft (hebres/arabic), then it require additional logic. and I did ugly solution like reverting the field content in code just for the pdf

Comment: I can't set the body style to align right, because only a few lines of the pdf should be right-aligned, not the whole body.